# ItemAdded Not Working

Tags: event-handlers, 2007

I’m trying to override the ItemAdded event handler for a Sharepoint 2007 document library. For some reason, it appears that the ItemAdded event is not firing. I can override the ItemAdding event no problem.

```
    override void ItemAdding(SPItemEventProperties properties)
    {
        Log("Item Adding");
    }

    override void ItemAdded(SPItemEventProperties properties)
    {
        Log("Item Added");
    }
```

When I check the log file, I see “Item Adding”, but not “Item Added”. I know ItemAdded is asynchronous, so I’ve waited a few minutes, and tried refreshing, but no luck. 
Any idea what could be happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check if the event ItemAdded is really attached to the document library. Something like the following should do the trick :

```
listName.EventReceivers.Add(SPEventReceiverType.ItemAdded, Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().FullName, typeof(YourItemReceiverClass).FullName);
```